# Invalid JSON - trying to nest an array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build a JSON object that will drive my web app, however I currently getting an invalid JSON object returned and I cannot see the problem,

I have run the JSON through [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and I am getting the following error,

> Parse error on line 19:
>   ...                   ]            },
>   ----------------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

My JSON object is below,

```
    {
    "name": "FF",
    "good": {

        "doors" : [
            {
                "name" : "Door Name 1",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/ff0000/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                     "Specifics 1a",
                    "Specifics 2a"
                ]   
            },
            {
                "name" : "Door Name 2",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/b4da55/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                    "Specifics 1b",
                    "Specifics 2b",
                    "Specifics 3b",
                ]   
            }, //LINE 19 - Where the JSON Lint states there to be an error.
            {
                "name" : "Door Name 3",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/0000ff/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                     "Specifics 1c",
                    "Specifics 2c",
                    "Specifics 3c",
                    "Specifics 4c"
                ]   
            },
        ],
        "walls" : [
            {
                "name" : "Chair Rail A",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/0000ff/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                    "Chair Rail A",
                ]   
            },
            {
                "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rosettes A",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/b4da55/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                    "Panel Moulding A",
                    "4\" Rossette"
                ]   
            },
            {
                "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rossettes B",
                "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/ff0000/ffffff",
                "specifics" : [
                    "Panel Moulding A",
                    "6\" Rossette"
                ]   
            },
        ],

    },
    "best": {},
    "better": {}
}
```

I assume that problem is coming from trying to have an array in object so I can have multiple options when looping, is this correct? And if so how should my JSON be formed?

Comment: `"Specifics 3b",` <= the comma is invalid

Comment: as @MichaelKunst points out.. extra comma.. remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the JSON is wrongly formatted. Here is the right format:

```
{
"name": "FF",
"good": {

    "doors" : [
        {
            "name" : "Door Name 1",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/ff0000/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                 "Specifics 1a",
                "Specifics 2a"
            ]   
        },
        {
            "name" : "Door Name 2",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/b4da55/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                "Specifics 1b",
                "Specifics 2b",
                "Specifics 3b"
            ]   
        },
        {
            "name" : "Door Name 3",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/0000ff/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                 "Specifics 1c",
                "Specifics 2c",
                "Specifics 3c",
                "Specifics 4c"
            ]   
        }
    ],
    "walls" : [
        {
            "name" : "Chair Rail A",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/0000ff/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                "Chair Rail A"
            ]   
        },
        {
            "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rosettes A",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/b4da55/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                "Panel Moulding A",
                "4\" Rossette"
            ]   
        },
        {
            "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rossettes B",
            "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/ff0000/ffffff",
            "specifics" : [
                "Panel Moulding A",
                "6\" Rossette"
            ]   
        }
    ]

},
"best": {},
"better": {}
}
```

You used too many commas in your json.

I use [jsoneditoronline.org](http://jsoneditoronline.org) to validate JSON and I find it very useful for the errors highlighting.

Comment: Note that while most implementations of JavaScript accept one trailing comma at the end of an object or an array, JSON is more strict than JavaScript and trailing commas are explicitly disallowed. For example, `[ "a", ]` is valid JavaScript, but `JSON.stringify('[ "a", ]'`) would fail (it's the same for objects).

Answer (score 1):

In a number of places in the JSON you have dangling commas. Get rid of those and your JSON will parse. I always find [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to be a helpful tool in these occasions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma after the array item, right here:

```
    "specifics" : [
        "Specifics 1b",
        "Specifics 2b",
        "Specifics 3b", //there is no next element, remove the ,
    ]
```

The same situation also occurs here:

```
    "specifics" : [
        "Chair Rail A",
    ]
```

There is also an extra comma after the walls property:

```
"walls" : [
    {
        "name" : "Chair Rail A",
        "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/0000ff/ffffff",
        "specifics" : [
            "Chair Rail A",
        ]   
    },
    {
        "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rosettes A",
        "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/b4da55/ffffff",
        "specifics" : [
            "Panel Moulding A",
            "4\" Rossette"
        ]   
    },
    {
        "name" : "Wall Paneling with Rossettes B",
        "thumb": "http://placehold.it/134x134/ff0000/ffffff",
        "specifics" : [
            "Panel Moulding A",
            "6\" Rossette"
        ]   
    },
], //Remove me
```

Answer (score 0):

you have invalid json format, with lot of `,` in your code, validate your json code in online.

Online Validator Tool:  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/